# How do I detect if Silverlight is enabled in Safari 7?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, safari

In Chrome and previous versions of Safari on Mac, I could detect whether Silverlight was enabled by calling `Silverlight.isInstalled(version)` using Silverlight.js, or just `navigator.plugins["Silverlight Plug-In"]` on non-IE browsers.

However, now it seems that if Silverlight isn't allowed, Safari ignores the `<object>` but still reports that the plugin is installed, so I can't detect whether Silverlight is available. Has anyone else had this problem?

Someone suggested making a test XAP that modifies some JS, but if it's possible to avoid adding another XAP, that'd be preferable.